# Predicting the products obtained after addition of bromine and then elimination using alcoholic KOH

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

If we have an alkene reacting with bromine, then I know that the the reaction happens by a cyclic intermediate. But if we add alcoholic KOH to the products formed, then what will be the major products formed?

I don't understand the meaning of *trans* addition in case of only one π and σ bonds where the bond formed after addition is free to rotate as it is σ bond.  If bromine adds in an *anti* manner, then can it not convert to the *cis* form?

I am not sure if using the terms like '*trans*' and '*cis*' in case of σ bond is correct. I am not sure whether it's a molecule of bromine or HBr will be eliminated after addition of alcoholic KOH.

Comment: HBr gets elimianted. Depending on the molecule you may get 1 or 2 equivalents of HBr lost so diene formation is possible.

Comment: @Waylander I am afraid. It's not very clear to me.

Comment: @Waylander can you please explain why will HBr be eliminated and not Br2 ?

Comment: The mechanism of alkene formation by KOH is removal of a proton by OH- to give H2O and leaving a carbanion. The carbanion very quickly eliminates Br-, KBr is formed in solution but overall the components of HBr are lost from the moelcule.